# Subplots not taking arguments

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I'm, trying to do a 3x9 subplots with a contourf from 3 lists, but when I plotted it it only apply the plot options (ylim, axis scaled, no axis tick) to the last plot, how can I instead apply to all the plots?
Furthermore all the plots results one on top of each other as illustrated in the pic below, how can I spaced them properly?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 9)
for j in range(len(axes[0])):
    
    levels = np.linspace(v_min, v_max, 21)
    for i in range(1, 19, 2):
        axes[0][j].contourf(V_avg[i], levels=levels, cmap=rgb_V)
    np.linspace(v_min, v_max, 11)
    
    for i in range(2, 20, 2):
        axes[1][j].contourf(V_avg[i], levels=levels, cmap=rgb_V)
    np.linspace(v_min, v_max, 11)
    
    levels = np.linspace(v_min_d_avg, v_max_d_avg, 21)
    for i in range(0, 9):
        axes[2][j].contourf(V_avg_dud[i], levels=levels, cmap=rgb_D_V)
    np.linspace(v_min_d_avg, v_max_d_avg, 11)

plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.ylim([15, 90])
plt.savefig("aaa", dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You probably want to set the limit of each ax individually with [set_ylim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim) or labels/ticks with [set_ylabel](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html) or [set_yticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `axes.flatten()` to loop through the subplots.

Here is a simple example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 9, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for ax in axes.flatten():
    x = np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=10)
    y = np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=10)
    ax.scatter(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Which produces this:

[image]

You don't give an example data set format, but here is an example where your data are in a dictionary:

```py
# Build example dataset
keys = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
data_dict = {}
for key in keys:
    data_dict[key] = [
        np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=10).tolist(),
        np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=10).tolist(),
    ]

# Loop through dictionary for plotting
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axes = axes.flatten()
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(data_dict.items()):
    x, y = value[0], value[1]
    axes[index].scatter(x, y)
    axes[index].set_title(key)

plt.show()
```

[image]